# MailChimp template: hideable block containing repeatable blocks can't be hidden

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I have a block in my MailChimp email template something like this:

> **Latest news**
>
> [Introductory text]
>
> [Repeatable news item]
>
> [Link to all news on site]

The whole block is set to be `mc:hideable`, and the news item uses `mc:repeatable`.

The problem is that when I hover over the area inside the block but outside the news item, I see the eye icon to hide the whole block - it appears in the middle, over the news item. But when I move to click it, the news item's edit / repeat control appear and the block's hideable icon disappears!

Am I missing something? The only workaround I can think of at the moment is creating 3 blocks, the heading / intro (hideable), and the news item (repeatable, presumably that can be hidden by removing the default item), and the link. They'll each need the same background colour and to fit flush together to look like one block, and in order to hide the lot editors will have to remember to hide each part. Seems a bit long-winded.

Answer (score 2):

Infuriating isn't it? Which is why I hacked Chimps own CSS by adding this to my template style tag CSS:

```
.tpl-hidewrap { left:auto !important; right:0 !important; }
```

Of course you could add different CSS to position it to suit your template, but it certainly worked for me, as the area to be hidden was wider than the repeating area.

Humans 1 Chimps 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

KevAdamson's answer was a good starting point for me. I had to go one step further though:

```
    .tpl-hidewrap {
      left: 0 !important;
      right: 0 !important;
      display: block !important;
      height: 100px !important;
      text-align: center;
    }
```